# Regex help needed. with pattern matching

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm new to Regex. 
The question asks me, Can you think of a regular expression to find spaces at the start and end of a string? Try it yourself before checking the spoiler below:

The solution is this:
     (?:^\s+)|(?:\s+$)

How does this Regex work?

Can you walk me through each step? 
What does this line of Regex do?
Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern ^\s+ will find leading whitespace,
and the pattern \s+$ will find trailing whitespace.

Hope you find that helpful.

You can read more about fun with [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2):

`()` match group.

`?:` make the expression "non-capturing".

`^` starts at the beginning of the string.

`$` matches the end of the string.

`|` means "or".

`\s` matches whitespace.

`+` greedy repetition. (see the link below for more info)

So put it all together and you get an expression that looks for whitespace at the beginning *OR* end of a string.

You can read more about fun with regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: The `?:` does not make it optional. Something in `(?: )` means it is a non-capturing group. But it is not optional. In fact, the expression mean to find 1 or more whitespace at the start of the text OR find 1 or more whitespace at the end of the text.

Comment: @rmaddy - Good call, +1. Copy and paste fail!

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to group anything with (?:).  The pattern `^\s+|\s+$` will work just as well.  Also, you might want to be wary of using \s in this case (in lieu of [ \t] for example), since it will also match newline characters (although this might be desired if you need to search for trailing newlines).

Answer (score 0):

This regex has two main parts, separated by `|`. It means that any string will be a match if it matches either `(?:^\s+)` or `(?:\s+$)`.

`^\s+` means "one or more whitespace symbols at the beginning of string".

`\s+$` means "one or more whitespace symbols at the end of string".

Any substring matching a regex inside `(?:)` will be saved for future use (it's called a match group). If all you need is to see if there's a match or not, you don't need to worry about it. In this case you can rewrite the regex as `^\s+|\s+$`

Comment: Actually, the `?:` indicates that the group is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

For Regex pattern

```
          ^\s+
```

will find leading whitespaces

and the pattern \s+$ will find trailing whitespace.

You can read more about fun with regular expressions via this link: